# Is Attribute based encryption sub-class of Identity based encryption

Tags: encryption, identity-based-encryption, abe

I have a basic question related to Identity and Attribute based encryption.

Construction of IBE scheme was first shown by Boneh et al. in 2001 and I think in 2004 Sahai and Waters introduced  Attribute based encryption in 2004 for multiple attributes. ABE extended to CPABE or KPABE schemes.

Can ABE schemes be considered as child of IBE schemes or ABE can be considered as subclass of IBE schemes. Or ABE schemes cannot be categorized as a variant of IBE scheme at all.

Is there a generic name under which I can group the IBE and ABE schemes? Please suggest.

Comment: ABE can be seen as a generalization of IBE. You can put them under functional encryption.

Comment: To add to what @DrLecter says, given an ABE scheme, you can construct an IBE scheme. You can't go the other way. The way to construct IBE from ABE is to give every participant in the system a single attribute. The attribute value is their identity.

Comment: @mikeazo Why not write up an answer in the duplicating question?